# flutter build apk --release fails while flutter build apk -- debug works fine

Tags: flutter

I need to release a signed apk for my flutter project, but the "flutter build apk --release" command fails.

The "flutter build apk --debug" command works fine.
I have checked the setup using "flutter doctor" and everything seems fine.
I have tried cleaning the project with flutter clean but it didn't help.

The error returned by the "flutter build apk --debug -v" is:

```
Gradle build failed to produce an Android package.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:24:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:484:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:346:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/apk.dart:34:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:51:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:559:18)
#6      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
#7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#9      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#10     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#11     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#12     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#13     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#14     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:33:20)
#15     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#16     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#17     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#20     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#21     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Comment: Link to full output: https://pastebin.com/uUt3Eymx

Answer (score 3):

Error was due to invalid password for the keystore. After fixing it, build compleded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

According to Android SDK docs you can use the following command depending on the sdkmanager location: Docs on --licenses option seems to be missing though.

```
yes | sdkmanager --licenses
```

**GNU/Linux Distributions:**

```
yes | ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

**macOS**:

export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\

```
Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
yes | ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

**Windows:**

```
%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

Run Flutter Clean Also

Answer (score 0):

If you have following this link properly of [Signing the app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app) if you want to upload it to play store then following command should work properly :

```
flutter build apk --release
```

If above doesn't work try to use :

```
flutter build apk  // this command default creates the release apk, but don't know if you can upload it to play store
```

Comment: I have already done that, the problem is that the build command fails.
As a note, i think that "flutter build apk" is exactly the same as "flutter build apk --reslease"

Comment: yes "flutter build apk" is the release apk, but i am not sure that you can upload it to play store.